# retrieve information from php file on 000webhost into android app

Tags: php, android, json

I want to get information from a php file hosted by 000webhost into my android app. I have tried xxxxxxx.netau.net/xxxx.php and my ip address as my url in my app but still doesn't work.I use a json parser to get the information i need.

Comment: run the file in browser to check what result are you getting because 000webhost attach some string with every file you host there. just echo the json values

Comment: if thats the issue then check my answer.. hope it will help you

Comment: i get the result i want and i have disabled it but is still not working @habibulhaq i works well when i use the same script for localhost

Comment: if the browser shows you the correct output then its not the fault from server side

Comment: ok.so should i use the website url or the ip address @habibulhaq

Comment: you should use website address in your app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if the problem is the extra string of 000webhost

then you can disable this extra js code by [this link](http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php)